# On express by using multer, how can I Upload file which is stored in req.body.files?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, multer

As far as I know, Multer uploads files which is stored in req.file.

But when I send file by using react with axios, the data is stored in req.body.file

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Here is my code.

**Send data by using axios**

```
function handleUpload() {

    const formData = new FormData();
    fileList.forEach(file => {
        formData.append('files', file);
    });

    setUpLoading(true);

    axios.post("http://localhost:3003/apis/board", formData, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    });
};
```

**Receving data on node.js by using express with multer**

```
var express = require('express');
const router = require('express').Router();

const multer = require('multer');
const cors = require('cors');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3003);
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, res, callback) {
        callback(null, "uploads/");
    },
});

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
});


app.post('/apis/board', upload.array('files'));
app.post('/apis/board', (req, res) => {
    const title = req.body.title;       
    const contents = req.body.contents; 
    const files = req.files;            

    console.log("req", req);
    console.log("req.files", files);
    console.log("req.body.files", req.body.files);
    
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port' + app.get('port'));
})
```

**When express got datas.
It shows req, req.files, req.body.files**

[image]

As you can see in the picture, file data is stored in req.body.files.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that you're uploading actual images and not text-data? I can only reproduce this if I upload text-data. Those are then populated under `req.body.<nameOfUsedField>`.

Comment: Hmm.. No matter how I look at it, I think it's a image file.